# cuda support on tegra2 chip

Tags: cuda, gpgpu, nvidia, tegra

I am working on a image processing project which utilizes cuda for gpgpu imlementation. I want to know is there cuda support enabled on NVIDIA'S tegra2 chip.

Answer (score 4):

> Covered in another thread: Tegra 2 doesn't support CUDA, and we can't
>   speak to future products.
>
> David Chait
>   Developer Technology Engineer
>   NVIDIA Corporation

[source](http://developer.nvidia.com/tegra/forum/opencl-cuda-support-tegra)

Answer (score 1):

Pointed out correctly Tegra 2 and Tegra 3 do not support CUDA.
Logan will be the first one supporting CUDA and OpenCL.

However, Nvidia is already trying to bring people to using CUDA with Tegras, at the moment you can use a Tegra 3 plus a Nvidia PCIe graphic card.

There are a few Development boards supporting that

- Nvidia Jetson: http://www.nvidia.com/object/jetson-automotive-developement-platform.html
- Nvidia Kayla
- Toradex Apalis: http://www.toradex.com/products/apalis-arm-computer-modules/apalis-t30