# What do I need for programming for Tegra GPU

Tags: android, cuda, gpgpu, tegra

Can I develop applications on CUDA processor Tegra 1/2, what do I need for this and what Tegra 1/2 CUDA-capability?
I found only NVIDIA Debug Manager for development in Eclipse for Android, but I do not know if he can develop a CUDA-style.

Comment: No, Tegra 1 & 2 don't support CUDA.

Comment: But how can I use Tegra GPU, OpenCL?

Comment: No, no OpenCL either. I think OpenGL ES is the only API supported on that hardware.

Comment: @talonmies you should post that as an answer! Otherwise this just shows up as unanswered...

Comment: @talonmies And can I develop programs for Tegra (such as the Android) with OpenGL ES API in Eclipse+NVIDIA Debug Manager?

Comment: Yes, you can use OpenGL ES on Tegra.  We posted some examples of GPU acceleration on Tegra here, http://accelereyes.com/mobile

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Current Tegra processors (Tegra 1, 2 and 3) do not support the CUDA platform. To learn about Tegra development and download the Tegra Android Development Kit, see the [NVIDIA developer zone for mobile](http://developer.nvidia.com/category/zone/mobile-development).

Answer (score 1):

See similar question/answers here:

- [CUDA support for NVIDIA Tegra 4 processors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14292609/cuda-support-for-nvidia-tegra-4-processors/16091968#16091968)
- [cuda support on tegra2 chip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6352478/cuda-support-on-tegra2-chip)

  ---

As pointed out correctly Tegra 2/3/4 do not support CUDA. Logan will be the first one supporting CUDA and OpenCL.

However, Nvidia is already trying to bring people to using CUDA with Tegras, at the moment you can use a Tegra 3 plus a Nvidia PCIe graphic card.

There are a few Development boards supporting that

Nvidia Jetson: http://www.nvidia.com/object/jetson-automotive-developement-platform.html
Nvidia Kayla
Toradex Apalis: http://www.toradex.com/products/apalis-arm-computer-modules/apalis-t30

Comment: Do you know about how this kit works? http://www.nvidia.com/object/seco-dev-kit.html it runs on Tegra 3 and contains a "CUDA Tool Kit"