# CUDA support for NVIDIA Tegra 4 processors?

Tags: c++, c, cuda, tegra

I could not find anything on the use of CUDA on Tegra processors,
even though they provide quite a lot SIMD cores (~72).
It would seem that NVIDIA currently focuses development efforts on Tegra
through the Tegra development kit (based on Android).

So my question is:
"Is it possible to use CUDA (or OpenCL) on Tegra 4 or predecessors and if so what version is supported?"

Comment: Tegra 4 isn't even on the market yet - it was only formally announced at CES a few days ago. Speculation about future hardware and software is off-topic for Stackoverflow. Older Tegra processors do not support CUDA.

Comment: Edited the question to exclude speculation. As you mentioned it was announced at CES so if anyone would like to share some recent insight I would definitely appreciate it.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/q/12394243/681865.

Comment: Thx for the link talonmies.

Comment: @Bart: be careful mixing terminologies here. Older Tegra parts *do* support GPGPU, via OpenGL-ES shaders. But they don't support CUDA or OpenCL.

Comment: @talonmies Yeah, absolutely right of course. Have left the shader-based GPGPU world behind me some time ago, so that was not on my mind.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

We were confused by the news articles too. We have since learned the following:

CUDA is not supported on Tegra 4, according to [this tweet](https://twitter.com/accelereyes/status/288791095603785729) ([also here](https://twitter.com/harrism/status/288789137320984578)) by SO user "harrism" who works for NVIDIA. It is anticipated for a future Tegra version (same tweet as a source).

OpenCL is not supported on Tegra.

OpenGL ES 2 shaders have always been supported on Tegra and here are some Tegra 2 and Tegra 3 [demos with these shaders](http://accelereyes.com/mobile) from our previous work at AccelerEyes.

We're looking forward to running our stuff on the 72 GPU cores though, using our ES 2 shaders. Awesome chip.

Cheers!

Comment: Ah, that's better information than provided by the (apparently misguided) news sites. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Pointed out correctly Tegra 2/3/4 do not support CUDA. Logan will be the first one supporting CUDA and OpenCL.

However, Nvidia is already trying to bring people to using CUDA with Tegras, at the moment you can use a Tegra 3 plus a Nvidia PCIe graphic card.

There are a few Development boards supporting that

- Nvidia Jetson: http://www.nvidia.com/object/jetson-automotive-developement-platform.html
- Nvidia Kayla
- Toradex Apalis: http://www.toradex.com/products/apalis-arm-computer-modules/apalis-t30